# BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) when I try rendering data with vtk

Tags: python, vtk, glx

I'm currently trying to follow this tutorial for my class. https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/volume-rendering-with-python-and-vtk/ I followed the instructions and my code matches up, but when I try to run it I get the following error.

> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
>
> Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> Serial number of failed request:  15
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  20

I've looked through other posts that have similar messages and they don't seem to be quite the same. Oh I'm also running Ubuntu 16.04 on a virtual machine. Please let me know of any suggestions you might have or any additional information you'd need to help resolve this issue.

As suggested by Antimony I uploaded my code to github, here

> https://github.com/alam38/lab6

I believe the relevant section is section involving the mapper. As you can see from the commented section I switched from vtk's vtkVolumeRayCastMapper to vtk's smartmapper as a suggestion from my teacher in the case that the issue stemmed from the mapper placing too much strain on my computer. The other similar questions all seem to point towards an issue with nvidia's drivers, but I updated my drivers and there's still an issue. That still didn't solve it and I'm not sure what else I could try.

Comment: It's a good idea to add the relevant portions from that link to your question, so that one doesn't have to refer to an external link and read through a long article to understand the problem.

Comment: you're right sorry I'm going to add my code right now, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

running gazebo on a VM doesn't go with 3d graphic driver,
but you could try these:

1) in VirtualBox go to settings - display - video - enable acceleration

2) on VirtualBox install:

`sudo apt remove libcheese-gtk23
 sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core`

then restart your VM OS

**I suggest you set-up dual boot**